# Sublime Text 3 - Vintageous - Can't search and replace newlines or carriage returns

Tags: regex, newline, sublimetext3

Not sure if this is me failing, or not using the right regex type or something - still fairly newb at it.

I just tried:

```
:%s/\n/,/g
```

I think that is right for replacing new lines with commas, but it doesn't work in Vintageous.

If I just use the normal GUI find and replace in Sublime Text 3, I can find and replace new lines (\n)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `:%s/\n/&44;/g` — does that work?

Comment: No search and replace is working for me with ST3 and Vintageous. :(